# How to change the date modified of youtube-dl files to date downloaded?

Tags: youtube-dl

If I download [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNZUIWXbHAM) with `youtube-dl`, the last modified date is `15 November 2018 03:55`, while YouTube shows a posted date of 23 April 2013. [This page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55770?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) mentions that one cannot replace a video:

> You can’t replace a video since any new video uploads will get a new URL

I would like to change that date to the date of the download, i.e. today, instead of that other date. The downloader launches asynchronously, so I can't easily pipe the filepath to `touch`. I have not found any option in the documentation. If I can't find any good solution, I will look at the Python source code and submit a pull request.

What is that date, and can I easily set the modified date to today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default youtube-dl sets the modified date of the filesystem to the Last-Modified header sent by Youtube. If you don't want that you can use the ''--no-mtime'' parameter which leaves the modified date unchanged so it is "now".

For more details see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387133

Answer (score 1):

you can easily convert the date to the current date, at least in win10, by using  the context of the downloaded file, then properties/details, and then scroll down to "media created". Here you can manually change (only) the date...

In python it is also possible, in case you have to do it several times...